# How can I use the DMA of a PIC24F microcontroller?

Tags: dma, pic24

I want to use the DMA of a PIC24FJ1024GB610 that I have. Basically, what I want is to read some analog inputs and store them in a memory space that the CPU can access whenever it wants to perform calculations with the measurement. I also want the ADC conversion to be triggered by a timer, any timer will do. However, I'm still having trouble understanding how to configure the DMA using MCC. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get started? I'll show you a photo of what appears in MCC:

[image]